# available memory in kernel

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel

Is there a kernel function which returns amount of kernel memory available(Not vmalloc related).

Comment: You already have a perfectly good indication of memory shortage (allocation returns `NULL`), why are you looking for another one?

Comment: Checking how much memory is available, especially in low-memory situations, would not work. Some other thread could have allocated whatever was left between the time you check and the time you allocate.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to allocate zero bytes? Check for that also.

Comment: loop through kmalloc with a smaller chunk every time until you get a valid pointer? It's brute force but might work

Comment: Internal fragmentation is a problem for the kernel, which means that even if there is a large amount of memory available, large allocations may still fail because there isn't enough *contiguous* memory available.

Comment: He didn't asked, how much memory he could allocate, he wants to ho much memory is available.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, let me say that if you're going to make any policy decisions (should I proceed with this operation?) based on this information, **STOP**. As WGW pointed out, there are unavoidable races here; memory can be used up between when you check and when you use it. Just test for errors on your memory allocations and have an appropriate failure path. Moreover, if you request memory when there isn't enough free memory, often the kernel can obtain more free memory by cleaning up various cache memory, swapping to disk, freeing slabs, etc. And kernel memory fragmentation can fail large (multiple page) allocations when not made through vmalloc even with plenty of memory free.

That said, there are APIs for querying kernel memory availability. You should note that the kernel has multiple memory pools, so even if one of these API says you have no free RAM, it could be that it's available in the memory pool you are interested in.

First, we have [si_meminfo](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.39/mm/page_alloc.c#L2442). This is the call that provides availability data for `/proc/meminfo`, among other things, and reports on the current state of the buddy page allocator. Note that cached and buffer ram can be converted to free ram very quickly.

`global_page_state(NR_SLAB_RECLAIMABLE)` can also be used to get counts of how much slab memory can be quickly reclaimed. If you request an allocation, this memory can and will be freed on demand.

The SLUB allocator (used for `kalloc()` and the like, among others) also provides statistics for its internal memory pools that can also reflect free memory within each memory pool. This may not be available with the same API depending on which allocator is selected in your configuration - please *do not use this data except for debugging*. The relevant code (implementing `/proc/slabinfo`) can be found in [mm/slub.c](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.39/mm/slub.c#L4845)

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't even very rough and race vulnerable info about available kernel memory be useful when dealing with memory leaks in kernel space? I mean checking available memory, then running X times a driver or whatever which allocates memory and finally checking how big will be the difference.

Answer (score 4):

What kind of use is the available memory for you? Worst case you run in a race condition with checking available memory:

1. You get the available memory. It`s enough.
2. Multitasking, a.k.a. the scheduler of the kernel, stops your process and continues with another one which allocates a bunch of the available memory.
3. The scheduler continues with your process.
4. Your allocations fails though step 1 showed enough available memory.

Comment: Please correct me if am wrong but AFAIK its simply that kmalloc() can always show success. But they actually doesnt mean that that memory is currently allocated. The pages for the memory are created when the task is actually accessing the memory that you have created.